# changing text properties as part of html script

Tags: javascript, python, html, http, simplehttpserver

I want to build a simple http server which receives list of text strings and sends simple dynamic html page which presents them in loop (similar to RSS)
It works fine but now I want to control text properties
How can I change text properties e.g. change background to transparent, text size and font?
The page is built using python HTTPserver module
It is sent single simple html page as a respond to GET request and I am not sure how I can embed css or other tricks in the script

Below python function receives string which contains list of strings (text) separated by commas, embeds it as array inside of html script (replaces TEXT with text) and sends it as part of html body in the respond

```
def write_response(self, text):
    print(content)
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
    self.end_headers()

    f = open('html.txt', "r")
    html = f.read()
    body = html.replace('TEXT', text)
    print(body)
    self.wfile.write(body.encode(encoding='utf-8'))
```

html.txt file

```
   <script>
        var example = [TEXT];

        textSequence(0);
        function textSequence(i) {

            if (example.length > i) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.getElementById("sequence").innerHTML = example[i];
                    textSequence(++i);
                }, 1000); // 1 second (in milliseconds)

            } else if (example.length == i) { // Loop
                textSequence(0);
            }

        }
    </script>

   <div id="sequence"></div>
```

Comment: it will be simpler if you use existings microframeworks like `Flask`

Comment: it seems you have to first learn `HTML` and `CSS`. And if you want to change it without reloading page then also `JavaScript` . And after that you may start to learning Python.

Comment: `RSS` is not page but method/file to share information - and programs or web pages (`RSS readers`) may display these information - Wikipedia: [RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS)

Comment: how about `.innerHTML = "<span style="color:red"> +  example[i] + "</span>"` ? But it would be simpler to define `CSS` classes in `<style></style>` and later use classes  `"<span class="top-text"> +  example[i] + "</span>"` but it means you have to learn `HTML` and `CSS` - so better find some tutorial for `HTML` and `CSS` because it will be better solution for you - you lean more in tutorial